# PIP Constraints Files

Tags: python, pip

I was reading the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) and couldn't wrap my head around it:

> Constraints files are requirements files that only control which
> version of a requirement is installed, not whether it is installed or
> not. Their syntax and contents is nearly identical to Requirements
> Files.
>
> There is one key difference: Including a package in a constraints file
> does not trigger installation of the package.

- So does that mean I need to requirement files first then run constraint?
- Need to have both requirements.txt and constraints.txt?
- Or just `-c requirements.txt`?

Could someone please explain in plain English that what the new PIP feature: **Constraints Files** does?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Update:** pip 20.3, released Nov 30, 2020, introduced [a new resolver](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-3-2020) that fixes some design issues. It also reimplements [the constraints feature](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files). It is now difficult or impossible to use the feature the way I describe below. I do not understand the new constraints implementation, and I no longer use it. I've had success with `pip-compile` from [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools). I specify top-level requirements in `requirements.in`, and `pip-compile` generates a `requirements.txt` with specific versions an package hashes. See [requirements.in](https://github.com/mozilla/ichnaea/blob/main/requirements.in) and [requirements.txt](https://github.com/mozilla/ichnaea/blob/main/requirements.txt) in the `ichnaea` project for a working example.

*Original answer below, for pip 20.2 and previous*

I think a constraints file is a good way to keep your "true" requirements separate from your full install list.

It's [good practice](http://12factor.net/dependencies) to fully specify package versions in your requirements file. For example, if you are installing [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with Django LTS, pin it to the latest releases (as of my answer):

```
Django==1.8.12
django-allauth==0.25.2
```

When you install the package, it ends up installing some required packages as well. So, you add those as well, so that everyone gets the same versions of packages:

```
Django==1.8.12
django-allauth==0.25.2
oauthlib==1.0.3
python-openid==2.2.5
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
```

And then you get the bug report "Doesn't work under Python 3". Oops, `python-openid` is Python 2 only, and `python3-openid` is used instead, further requiring `defusedxml`:

```
Django==1.8.12
django-allauth==0.25.2
oauthlib==1.0.3
python-openid==2.2.5   ; python_version < '3.0'
python3-openid==3.0.10 ; python_version >= '3.0'
defusedxml==0.4.1      ; python_version >= '3.0'
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
```

Now requirements.txt is getting ugly, and it's hard to see the "requirements" of Django and django-allauth in the mess.

Here is a `requirements.txt` that refers to a constraints file:

```
-c constraints.txt
Django==1.8.12
django-allauth==0.25.2
```

And `constraints.txt` with a helpful comment:

```
# django-allauth requirements
oauthlib==1.0.3
python-openid==2.2.5
python3-openid==3.0.10
defusedxml==0.4.1
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
```

No Python classifiers are needed, because constraints are only installed if a package requires them, and are ignored otherwise. Additionally, if a package stops requiring another package 2 years down the road, fresh installs will stop installing it.

I think this, plus some comments, is a useful way to communicate what packages you are using for the project, and which ones are included because they are dependencies.

I think it gets even more useful if you are using pip 8.x's [hash-checking mode](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode), which requires specifying versions for dependencies-of-dependencies. If you go down that path, I recommend [hashin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashin) to help you manage the hashes.  See [browsercompat](https://github.com/mdn/browsercompat/tree/master/requirements) for a complicated requirements setup using constraints and hashes.

Comment: Hi I am a bit confused that specifying `python-openid==2.2.5` and `python3-openid==3.0.10` in constraint will help determine which one to use based on python version?

Comment: The code that picks ``python-openid`` or ``python3-openid`` based on the Python version is in [django-allauth's setup.py](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/setup.py#L107-L111). If you are on Python 2.x, ``django-allauth`` will request ``python-openid >= 2.2.5``, and the ``constraints.txt`` file will say "and make it exactly version 2.2.5".

Comment: @jwhitlock By including `-c constraints.txt` on top of the `requirements.txt` file `pip install` will pick it up. But how do you make it work for `pip freeze -r requirements.txt`? (isn't that gonna throw an `Invalid requirement: '-c constraints.txt'` ?)

Comment: @RuiCarvalho yes, I get ``Invalid requirement: '-c constraints.txt'`` with pip 19.03. I think constraints are incompatible with ``pip freeze`` workflows. I might use ``pip freeze`` at the start of a project (if I remember it exists), but I hand-maintain requirements files for mature, complex projects, where constraints are worth the maintenance trouble.

Comment: @jwhitlock re: "I do not understand the new constraints implementation" — what you describe is a bug that is tracked @ https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9243

Answer (score 19):

From the book ["Secret Recipes of the Python Ninja"](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/secret-recipes-python-ninja)

Constraints files differ from requirements files in one key way: putting a package in the constraints file does not cause the package to be installed, whereas a requirements file will install all packages listed. Constraints files are simply requirements files that control which version of a package will be installed but provide no control over the actual installation.

Let say you have requirements.txt file with following code

```
# requirements.txt
pandas
```

and constraints.txt

```
# constraints.txt
 # math / science / graph stuff
  bokeh==0.11.1
  numpy==1.10.4
  pandas==0.17.1
  scipy==0.17.0
  openpyxl==2.3.3
  patsy==0.4.1
  matplotlib==1.5.1
  ggplot==0.6.8
  seaborn==0.7.0
  scikit-learn==0.17
```

executing

`pip install -c constraints.txt`

will install all packages from requirements.txt and using constraints.txt file for version constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Constraint files are very useful when you provide production environments with optimized package compilations for the productive infrastructure.

We provide such environments in docker containers with versions of numpy, scipy, tensorflow, opencv, ... optimized for our production servers. In order to ensure that the requirements files developers set up to make the environment reproducible for them don't overwrite these optimized installations, we use constraint files. They are written as part of the build process. pip is made aware of the constraints by setting the `PIP_CONSTRAINT` environment variable.

Before, developers always had to make sure their requirements line up with what's available in the prod containers, which can be a pain given that some minor version numbers iterate quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used constrains files myself, so I may be wrong, but here's how I understand it from the documentation.

Let's say, you have multiple projects which you install using pip. Some of them depend on a popular package *foobar* directly, some indirectly (via their dependencies), some don't depend on it at all.

One day you decide to change *foobar* code a bit, to solve some problem related to your environment, so you go ahead and create a local copy of *foobar*. Now you want to ensure that all your projects use this local copy, but you don't want to spend time figuring out which of them depend on *foobar* and then editing their `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` files.

Here comes constraints file, where you point out to your local copy of *foobar* and use it for all your projects, not caring which of them need *foobar*, because constrains file only applies when the project being installed actually depends on *foobar* (whether directly or indirectly).

---

There's an even better example of possible usage on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3k41zf/pip_71_constraints/cuvjs3u).

Comment: so how do you use it in conjunction with requirement files

Comment: @JamesLin not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here's one possible scenario: your requirements.txt contains single package Flask. It depends on Werkzeug which you modified for whatever reason and want Flask to depend on your local version. So you place it into constraints.txt and run `pip install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt`. In this simplistic case you could do with requirements.txt only, but using constrains.txt makes more sense when you have multiple projects with complex dependency trees.