# How to pin version of ancestor dependencies in Pip?

Tags: python, pip

We are developing a Python-based service that has several pip dependencies.

The dependencies are listed in a requirements.txt file with **pinned** versions
i.e:

```
package_a==1.0.0
package_b==2.0.0
```

So we are running the `pip install -e requirements.txt`.

Lately, we are facing problems where the dependencies of the listed packages have breaking interfaces in the newer versions and they are installed automatically because the version specifier in the `setup.py` file of `package_a` for example is: "`package_x >= 2.0`".

So once there is a `package_x` with version `3.0` - it is installed and breaks the software.

We thought out of a number of ways to handle this:

1. Deploying our own local pip repository and managing the specific versions we want to handle (but this might cause problems as the software evolves and we'll require to build old versions)
2. Running a `pip3 freeze` on all the systems and putting everything inside requirements.txt including the dependencies of the dependencies with pinned versions
3. Using the constraints feature by pinning the versions of the dependencies of dependencies keeping the requirements file as is and executing `pip3 install -r requrements.txt -c constraints.c`. So in this case the constraints will have the `"package_x==2.0"` value.

We saw some resources related to that but didn't get to a clear conclusion if this should be #2 or #3 or any other solution that is better for this use case. ([1](https://code-maven.com/python-package-dependency-management),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645821/pip-constraints-files),[3](https://blog.inedo.com/python-package-dependency-managament-demystified))

Please advice.

Comment: Try using `pip-tools` to generate a `requirements.txt` containing all of the pinned deps from a `requirements.in` file or from `setup.py`. This seems to be the least terrible solution I found.