# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.slack' Airflow 2.0 (MWAA)

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am using Airflow 2.0 and have installed the slack module through requirements.txt in MWAA. I have installed all the below packages, but still, it says package not found

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.slack'.
```

But it still gives me an error saying module not found. What should do ?

Please find the Requirements here :

```
alembic
anyio
apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon
apache-airflow-providers-amazon
apache-airflow-providers-ftp
apache-airflow-providers-http
apache-airflow-providers-imap
apache-airflow-providers-slack
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
apispec
argcomplete
asn1crypto
attrs
Babel
beautifulsoup4
blinker
boto3
botocore
cached-property
cachelib
cattrs
certifi
cffi
chardet
charset-normalizer
click
clickclick
colorama
colorlog
commonmark
configparser
connexion
croniter
cryptography
decorator
defusedxml
Deprecated
dill
dnspython
docutils
email-validator
Flask
Flask-Admin
Flask-AppBuilder
Flask-Babel
Flask-Caching
Flask-JWT-Extended
Flask-Login
Flask-OpenID
Flask-Session
Flask-SQLAlchemy
flask-swagger
Flask-WTF
funcsigs
future
graphviz
gunicorn
h11
httpcore
httpx
idna
importlib-metadata
importlib-resources
inflection
install
iso8601
itsdangerous
Jinja2
jmespath
json-merge-patch
jsonpath-ng
jsonschema
lazy-object-proxy
lockfile
lxml
Mako
Markdown
MarkupSafe
marshmallow
marshmallow-enum
marshmallow-oneofschema
marshmallow-sqlalchemy
mypy-boto3-rds
mypy-boto3-redshift-data
natsort
packaging
pandas
pendulum
ply
prison
psutil
pycparser
Pygments
PyJWT
pyparsing
pyrsistent
python-daemon
python-dateutil
python-nvd3
python-slugify
python3-openid
pytz
pytzdata
PyYAML
redshift-connector
requests
rfc3986
rich
s3transfer
scramp
setproctitle
six
slack-sdk
slackclient
sniffio
soupsieve
SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy-JSONField
sqlalchemy-redshift
SQLAlchemy-Utils
swagger-ui-bundle
tabulate
tenacity
termcolor
text-unidecode
thrift
typing_extensions
tzlocal
unicodecsv
urllib3
watchtower
websocket-client
Werkzeug
wrapt
WTForms
zipp
zope.Deprecation
```

Thanks for your help.

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Can you share the relevant source code and requirements.txt file?

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: Double checking: Did you update the requirements.txt object version ID for the MWAA environment?

Comment: If you meant "did you take the latest version of the requirement.txt" yes I always browse s3 and select requirement.txt

Comment: can you please help me out @AndrewNguonlyrew

Comment: What version of `apache-airflow-providers-slack`? Can you post the source code that is causing the error?

Comment: apache-airflow-providers-slack==4.2.3,
There is no error in local, but when pushed to MWAA. I am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found was using constraints at the top of `requirements.txt` as answered by Andrew Nguonly (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt) and confirming that all dependencies were properly installed. A depreciated package name blocked the installation of the `airflow.providers.slack` package for me.  You can check for any failures via this guide and rename your packages correctly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#working-dags-dependencies-logs.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MWAA is constrained to using version `3.0.0` for the package `apache-airflow-providers-slack`. If you specify version `4.2.3` in `requirements.txt`, it will not be installed (error logs should be available in CloudWatch). You'll have to downgrade to version `3.0.0`.

[`apache-airflow-providers-slack` (constraints.txt)](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/config/constraints.txt#L99)

**OR**

Add constraints file to the top of `requirements.txt` to use version `4.2.3` of `apache-airflow-providers-slack`.

> Add the constraints file for your Apache Airflow v2 environment to the top of your requirements.txt file.

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-main/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

[Installing Python dependencies using PyPi.org Requirements File Format (MWAA)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-dependencies.html#best-practices-dependencies-different-ways)
[Constraints files (Airflow)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/installation.html#constraints-files)

Comment: I tried it ,I got an error
  Cannot install apache-airflow-providers-slack==3.0.0 and apache-airflow-providers-slack==4.2.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
How would I uninstall current version?

Comment: Where Do you give this constraints file in MWAA? CLI?

Comment: Add the constraints at the top of `requirements.txt`. See this Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645821/pip-constraints-files

Comment: was previously using Airflow 2.2.2,I have relaunched it with Airfow2.0.2 and kept the slack version as given to you. It worked as expected. 
Thank you for your help.