How to use different requirement file based on python version in pyproject.toml
package support multiple version of python 2.7 and 3.9. Need to use the pyproject.toml for package.
How to specify a different requirement file based on python version ?
[project]
dynamic = ["dependencies"]
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}

found this How to reference a requirements.txt in the pyproject.toml of a setuptools project?

Maybe you're searching for requirement constraints? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36848206/21303427

for python3.9
dependencies = [
"click ; python_version == '3.9'",
]
for python2.7
dependencies = [
"click ==someversion; python_version == '3.9'",
]
like this , is any to use requirement3.9.txt for python3.9 and requirement2.7.txt for python2.7
